# How to turn on less secure app access on google?

Tags: security, gmail-api, google-account

There is no option for turn on less secure app access

[image: Less secure app access]

[image: learn more]

***Is there any another way to turn on less secure app access???***

Comment: TLDR: login with your phone and enable 2FA, then generate an "app password".

Answer (score 33):

As of May 30 2022 google has removed the less secure apps option. There is no way to turn this on as it no longer exists.

If you are trying to use Google smtp server you have two options

1. Enable 2fa on your google account and create an apps password and use that in place of your true password in your code.
2. switch to using Xoauth2 most of the libraries support it.  it will depend upon the language you are using though.

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Comment: This is an excellent guide to set up 2fa: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-automate-emails-with-python-8b476045c151

Comment: 1st option worked for me!

Comment: Very helpful - link was super useful too

Answer (score 20):

Note: 2-factor authentication needs to be enabled if not enabled already.

Less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) options is disabled.

Instead use apppasswords using following link.
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords

Use 16 digit code provided by google instead of password and that should be it.

[image]

Comment: The App Passwords section can also be found by navigating to [Security](https://myaccount.google.com/security), then [2FA](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification) in the block named "How you login", then scroll to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the spaces in the password should not be there.  Sometimes a copy/paste leaves them in there.  I'm perplexed at why google would do this since password "readability" is a thing that hasn't been a thing in years.  It should be copy-paste at a minimum....

TL;DR: NO SPACES

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using it with the spaces, and it works.